# Defining homomorphism $j:H_n(C)\otimes G\to H_n(C; G)$ in chain complex $C\otimes G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

My book is studying the following chain complex:
$$C\otimes G:\cdots \to^{\partial_{n+1}^{*}}C_{n+1}\otimes G \to^{\partial_{n}^{*}}C_{n}\otimes G\to \cdots$$

of the already chain complex

$$C:\cdots \to C_{n+1}\to^{\partial_{n+1}} C_{n}\to^{\partial_{n}} \cdots$$

It says the following: ($H_n = Z_n/B_n$ is the $n$-homology)

> Let's define an homomorphism
>
> $$j:H_n(C)\otimes G\to H_n(C; G)$$
>
> Let
>
> $$p:Z_n(C)\to H_n(C)$$ $$q:Z_n(C\otimes G)\to H_n(C; G)$$
>
> denote the natural projections. To define $j$, let $x\in H_n(C)$ and
>   $g\in G$ be given arbitraly. Select an element
>
> $$z\in Z_n(C)\subset C_n$$
>
> satisfying $p(z) = x$. Since $z\in C_n$ and $g\in G$, we have that
>   $z\otimes g\in C_n\otimes G$. Since
>
> $$\partial_n^{*}(z\otimes g) = (\partial_n z)\otimes (ig) = 0\otimes g
>  = 0$$
>
> we have $z\otimes g\in Z_n(C\otimes G)$. We can check that the element
>
> $$q(z\otimes g)\in H_n(C; G)$$
>
> **doesn't depend on the choice of $z\in Z_n(C)$** satisfying $p(z) = x$
>   and so is completely determined by $x\in H_n(C)$ e $g\in G$.

In case some information is missing, I've uploaded the entire section here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7P9o.jpg

So... Why is $q$ well defined? Why it doesn't depend on the choice of $z$? Is it because no matter which $z$ I take, if it has $x$ as projection, then $\partial_n z = 0$? (Also, why $\partial_n^{*}(z\otimes g) = (\partial_n z)\otimes (ig)$?).

The book also finishes this section saying that it's easy to verify that $j$ is an homomorphism... Why exactly?

Comment: What problem exactly are you having in showing that j is a homomorphisms? It is quite difficult to define functions going out of tensor products which are *not* homomorphisms, in fact!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez once I apply it to a sum I don't know what to do :c

Comment: But how did you construct the function with domain a tensor product? As I said: it is not at all obvious how to define functions going out of a tensor product which are **not** homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $H_n(C;G)$ is the $n$-th homology of the complex $C\otimes G$:
$$H_n(X;G)=\frac{Z_n(C\otimes G)}{B_n(C\otimes G)}$$
so there's a natural projection map $q:Z_n(C\otimes G)\to H_n(C;G)$.

If $p(z)=p(z')=x$ then $z'-z\in\ker p=B_n(C)$, so $z'-z=\partial y$
for some $y\in C_{n+1}$. Then $$z\otimes g-z'\otimes g=\partial(y)\otimes g
=\partial^*(y\otimes g)\in B_n(C\otimes G).$$ Therefore $z'\otimes g$
represents the same element of $H_n(C;G)$ as does $z\otimes g$.

Comment: But why $j$ is an homomorphism?

Comment: Also, why $q$ is called projection? Isn't the module $Z_n$ one of the modules of $Z_n/B_n$? For me this would be an inclusion

Comment: Do you mean $ker p = Z_n$ instead of $B_n$?

Comment: I just opened a bounty, would be glad if you could answer me these things

Comment: Also, shouldn't I show that $q(z\otimes g)\in H_n(C; G)$ and $q(z'\otimes g)\in H_n(C; G)$ are the same? Is it just because $z\otimes g$ and $z'\otimes g$ are the same?